# Page Loader while php processing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want simple loader on php page. 
Stages:
1. At first, I post file data to another php page `abc.php` through form submit.
2. `abc.php` takes much time to execute query because there is a `condition` for every record in file
3. Depending on condition loop inserts data.  Every record may satisfy different condition.
4. php page starts with `SESSION`.

When I run simple code in a sample file..
The code will run smoothly.  But not executable on php page.
Sample file code is -

```
<div id="overlay"></div><iframe src="abc.php">>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>
```

css-

```
#overlay{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: gray;
        position: fixed;
        margin: -0.7%;
        opacity: 0.6
    }
```

with a script at the end as -

```
var ol = document.getElementById("overlay"); window.addEventListener("load", function(){ ol.style.display="none"; });
```

This code is executable.  But not for php file. 
Want to run this code while executing abc.php after form submission.

ImportMain.php containing form-

```
<form id="upload_csv" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="abc.php" onsubmit="return Validate()" name="myform">

    <div id="File">
        <div><h4 STYLE="TEXT-ALIGN: CENTER; COLOR: brown;">IMPORT FILE</h4></div>
        <!--UPLOAD FILE--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <input type="file" name="uploadfile" class="fileInput">         

        <!--UPLOAD FILE ERROR MESSAGE------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <div id="uploadfile_error" class="val_error"></div>             

        <!--ADD CAMPIGN NAME---------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <div id="CampaignSearch">
            <input type="text" name="CampaignName" class="typeahead tt-query textInput" 
            id="search_text" placeholder="Campaign Name" 
            style="background: white;">
        </div>

        <!--EMPTY CAMPAIGN NAME ERROR MESSAGE---------------------------------------------------------------->
        <div id="CampaignName_error" class="val_error"></div>           

        <div id="ProjectDetails">
            <!--PROJECT NAME--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <input type="text" name="ProjectName" class="textInput" placeholder="Project Name">         

            <!--PROJECT NAME ERRRO MESSAGE----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <div id="ProjectName_error" class="val_error"></div>        

            <!--WORK ID--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <input type="text" name="WorkId" class="textInput" Placeholder="WorkId"">           

            <!--WORK ID ERROR MESSAGE------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <div id="WorkId_error" class="val_error"></div>     

            <!--CLIENT NAME--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <input type="text" name="ClientName" class="textInput" Placeholder="Client Name"">          

            <!--WORK ID ERROR MESSAGE------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <div id="ClientName_error" class="val_error"></div> 

            <!--CLIENT NAME--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <input type="text" name="ManagerName" class="textInput" Placeholder="Manager"">         

            <!--WORK ID ERROR MESSAGE------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <div id="ManagerName_error" class="val_error"></div>    
        </div>

        <!--SUBMIT BUTTON------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
        <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 3px;">   
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD" class="bn">
        </div>

        <!--SAMPLE CSV FORMAT-------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <div id="csvformat">
            <img src="images/csvformat.png" height="45" width="300" >       
        </div>

    </div>
```

abc.php -

```
session_start();if(!isset($_SESSION['login_status'])){  header("Location: Main.php") ;   }

/*INSERT CAMPAIGN NAME------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    $CampaignId=$_SESSION['CampaignId'];
    //ECHO $CampaignId;
    $Dup_Database=0;

    $Q1 = "SELECT * FROM 1.Contacts where CampaignId='$CampaignId'";
    $R1 = mysqli_query($conn, $Q1);

    IF ($R1->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        WHILE($ROW1=MYSQLI_FETCH_ARRAY($R1))
        {
            $email=$ROW1['EmailAddress'];

            $Q3 = "SELECT * FROM 1.Contacts where EmailAddress='$email' AND CampaignId <> '$CampaignId' AND EmailStatus<>'SUPPRESSED' AND RPAStatus='COMPLETE' ORDER BY EvaContactid DESC; ";
            $R3 = mysqli_query($conn, $Q3);


            /*INSERT FOR DUPLICATE RECORDS----------*/
            IF ($R3->num_rows > 0) 
            {   

                WHILE($ROW3=MYSQLI_FETCH_ARRAY($R3))
                {
                    $EmailStatus=$ROW3['EmailStatus'];
                    $EmailDetails=$ROW3['EmailDetails'];
                    $RPADetails=$ROW3['RPADetails'];
                    $ErrorDetails=$ROW3['ErrorDetails'];
                    $PCName=$ROW3['PCName'];
                    $Dup=$ROW3['Dup']+1;
                    $SentStamp=$ROW3['SentStamp'];
                    $ReadStamp=$ROW3['ReadStamp'];
                    $ProfileId=$ROW3['ProfileId'];
                    $ActionDate=$ROW3['ActionDate'];
                    $StartTime=$ROW3['StartTime'];
                    $EndTIme=$ROW3['EndTIme'];
                    $AHT=$ROW3['AHT'];

                    $query = "UPDATE 1.Contacts 
                      SET 
                      CampaignId='$CampaignId', 
                      empId='{$_SESSION['login_status']}', 
                      EmailStatus='$EmailStatus', 
                      EmailDetails='$EmailDetails',
                      RPAStatus='COMPLETE',
                      RPADetails='$RPADetails', 
                      ErrorDetails='$ErrorDetails',
                      PCName='$PCName',
                      Dup='$Dup',
                      SentStamp='$SentStamp',
                      ReadStamp='$ReadStamp',
                      ProfileId='$ProfileId',
                      ActionDate=now(), 
                      StartTime='$StartTime',
                      EndTIme='$EndTIme',
                      AHT='$AHT'
                      WHERE EmailAddress='$email' AND CampaignId = '$CampaignId' AND RPAStatus='PENDING'
                     ";

                    mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                    $Dup_Database++;

                    break;
                }

            }else{
                /*----*/
            }


        }
    }
    $Data_Remain = $Unique_Record - $Dup_Database;
    $_SESSION['Data_Remain']=$Data_Remain;
```